how to displace a mesh based off another mesh
i have a subdivided plane, with two other meshes, one is higher than the plane, the other is lower. i need to find a way to stretch the plane to meet the higher mesh when its under it, and stretch below to meet the lower mesh when the plane is above it, and when theres neither mesh above or below it, it stays the same. id love to do this manually, but i need to do this 80 ish times on very high resolution planes, so thats not exactly an option.

I would suggest the Shrinkwrap modifier in Project mode, with a limit on the distance.
Here is the two object projection.  I'm not sure if one could stack them for >2 object attractions.

my example: 
I you want some reverberation dynamic, I would instead use a cloth simulation, set Gravity=0,  add (large value) forces to the spheres (or forces with copy-location of spheres).
